# Print out the ansible host name

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

One of the task of my ansible playbook is below, and this playbook suppose to bring up an EC2 instance:

```
TASK: [Demo] ******************************************************************
changed: [ec2-52-24-222-200.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com] => (item=ec2.instances)
```

How can I print out or create a folder with the name`ec2-52-24-222-200.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` on Ansible

Comment: What does your playbook do? Can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: This playbook suppose to bring up an ec2 instance on AWS. I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hostname as defined in your inventory is stored in the variable `inventory_hostname`.

So to *print out* the host name you would do:

```
- debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

To create a directory:

```
- file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    state: directory
```

If you meant by "on Ansible" that you want to create the directory on the Ansible control host, you need to delegate the task:

```
- file:
    path: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    state: directory
  delegate_to: localhost
```